# NoMethodError (undefined method `close' for #<StockQuote::Stock:0x007fe59ffb1788> Did you mean? clone):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the udemy course on building the finance tracker app. unfortunately, I've encountered this problem and I'm unable to solve it in any way. I'm using ruby 5.1.4. here's the full error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `close' for
>    Did you mean?  clone):

here's my stocks_controller:

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  def search
    if params[:stock]
      @stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(params[:stock])
      @stock ||= Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
    end

    if @stock
      render partial: 'lookup'
    else
      render status: :not_found, nothing: true
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the stock.rb model:

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord

  def self.find_by_ticker(ticker_symbol)
    where(ticker: ticker_symbol).first
  end

  def self.new_from_lookup(ticker_symbol)
    looked_up_stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker_symbol)
    return nil unless looked_up_stock.name
    new_stock = new(ticker: looked_up_stock.symbol, name: looked_up_stock.name)
    new_stock.last_price = new_stock.price
    new_stock
  end

  def price
    closing_price = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker).close
    return "#{closing_price}(Closing)" if closing_price
    opening_price = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker).open
    return "#{opening_price}(Opening)" if opening_price
    'Unavailable'
  end
end
```

I've practically followed the whole course, but problem started when i tried to access the stock from rails console using this command:

StockQuote::Stock.quote("GOOG").open

and got this error:

> NoMethodError: private method `open' called for

with this command:

```
StockQuote::Stock.quote("GOOG").close
```

I get this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `close' for
>           # Did you mean?  clone

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced the same problem with creating an app for stock tracker but I have resolved this by below steps.

Try to the following

Comment on this method

```
# Comment
#def price
   # closing_price = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker).close
    #return "#{closing_price}(Closing)" if closing_price
    #opening_price = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker).open
    #return "#{opening_price}(Opening)" if opening_price
   # 'Unavailable'
#end
```

Put that code

```
def self.new_from_lookup(ticker_symbol)
    begin
        looked_up_stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker_symbol)
        price = strip_commas(looked_up_stock.l)
        new(name: looked_up_stock.name, ticker: looked_up_stock.symbol, last_price: price)
    rescue Exception => e
        return nil
    end
end

def self.strip_commas(number)
    number.gsub(",", "")
end
```

Instead of current code

```
#def self.new_from_lookup(ticker_symbol)
    #looked_up_stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker_symbol)
    #return nil unless looked_up_stock.name
    #new_stock = new(ticker: looked_up_stock.symbol, name: looked_up_stock.name)
    #new_stock.last_price = new_stock.price
    #new_stock
#end
```

**Update 1**

Under `<%= render 'commom/spinner' %>` this line add like below

```
<% if @stock %>
    <strong>Symbol:</strong> <%= @stock.ticker %>
    <strong>Name:</strong> <%= @stock.name %>
    <strong>Price:</strong> <%= @stock.price %>
<% end %>
```

And see what happaning

Hope to help

Comment: hi @fool-dev, tried your solution but still got the same errors, unfortunately.

Comment: You can comment out `@stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(params[:stock])
` from controller and edit  `@stock ||= Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])`, remove `||` from this line and restar server, see what happanes

Comment: I've just tried that. same errors. with     StockQuote::Stock.quote("GOOG").open i get : NoMethodError: private method `open' called for #<StockQuote::Stock:0x007ffe1562bd10>

Comment: hi @fool-dev. solved the problem. turns out the methods have changed after the update to the gem. new methods for almost all previous previous ones. i was calling the wrong methods all along

Comment: Was this helpful from my answer?

Comment: yeah. still had to replace the code with yours for it to work. Error doesn't show now, and neither do stocks. New error: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template stocks/search, application/search with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.

Comment: Yeah! that is working but you have missed search page inside stocks folder

Comment: according to the tutorial its supposed to be rendered using AJAX on the same page. guess I might have a problem with that side of it? could it be the cause?

Comment: Then the partial are missing like `_list.html.erb` or `_stocks.html.erb` or something you can follow the course carefully ask to instructor if you do not find something helpful

Comment: could you please check out why its still not rendering? Shows in terminal that everything has worked, but there's not output in the browser I've been stuck here for days now. Thanks. https://github.com/chrisbillions/finance-app

Comment: @ChristianDziwornu see the Update 1 on my answer

Comment: tried it. same issue. shows its rendered in the terminal. but nothing in browser. sorry to be disturbing you so much with this issue. I'm a newbie

Comment: yes, i actually have. i understand what's happening basically, except the fact that it's not working for me.

Comment: You need to teste fetching data without any ajax code just manually it will work then use ajax for nicer